# How to retry input after an InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, validation, exception, try-catch, user-input

I am creating a program that takes input from the user.Now I want to re-run the input option if a user enters an invalid command. Like here only integer input are preferred but if the user inputs text, then I want to catch the exception and rerun the method.

I have tried this but it turns me into an infinite loop.What would be the best way to achieve this. It would be great if someone helps me on this.

```
    boolean retry = true;

    while(retry){

        try{
            //considering response from the user
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your Command : ");
             f_continue =  processresponse(scanner.nextInt());
             retry = false;
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){

            System.err.println("\nPlease Input a Valid Command from 1-5 or 0 for Exit");




        }

    }
```

Comment: You can read more about handling scanner input here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter something other than an integer, `nextInt()` will throw an exception, and what was entered will still be in the input buffer, so the next time you call `nextInt()`, you will read the same bad input. You should first call `hasNextInt()` to see if the input is an integer; if not, just call `nextLine()` to skip the bad input (and write a message telling the user to re-try).

Or you can just call `scanner.nextLine()` in the catch block.